# Tornado websocket messages aren't receiving

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a very simple setup inspired by this question: [Tornado - Listen to multiple clients simultaneously over websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202474/tornado-listen-to-multiple-clients-simultaneously-over-websockets)

Essentially, I have one Websocket Handler that may connect to many websocket clients. Then I have another websocket handler 'DataHandler' that will broadcast a message everytime it receives a message.

So I made a global list of TestHandler instances and use it to broadcast messages to all the instances

```
ws_clients = []

class TestHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print('open test!')
        ws_clients.append(self)
        self.random_number = random.randint(0, 101)

    def on_message(self, message):
        print(message)

        print('received', message, self, self.random_number)
        self.write_message('Message received')

    def on_close(self):
        print('closed')


class DataHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print('data open!')

    def on_message(self, message):
        for c in ws_clients:
            c.write_message('hello!')


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/test_service/", TestHandler),
            (r"/data/", DataHandler),
            (r"/", httpHandler)
        ]

        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)


ws_app = Application()
ws_app.listen(8000)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

TestHandler can receive messages fine through the address `ws://127.0.0.1/test_service/` and DataHandler can receive messages fine through the address `ws://127.0.0.1/data/` but whenever I loop through `ws_clients`, I never receive any messages on `TestHandler`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you also expecting to see the message on websocket connected to `DataHandler`? That won't happen because in `c.write_message('hello')` you're sending out the message to connections in `ws_clients` only. You're not sending message to the websocket connected to `DataHandler`, if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: Ah! I see, I just tested it and it confirms what you said. In that case... what could I do to modify the code so that any message that gets sent to `DataHandler` can get routed to the `on_message` method of all the instances of `TestHandler`?

Comment: I'm a little confused with what you're trying to do. If you're sending a message to clients inside `ws_clients`, then you should see the message on the client side. You won't receive those messages on `TestHandler`. The `on_message` function invokes when the **client sends the message to the handler**. But when you use `c.write_message`, you're actually sending the message to the client.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is I have `TestHandler` that is constantly sending an integer value `var` via websocket to many external devices with different instances. However, the value of `var` that is sent to each of these devices needs to change over time and this change is dependent on another script - call it script X. Script X determines the value of `var` for each instance of `TestHandler`. But Script X is external and therefore has no direct access to `var` for each instance of `TestHandler`. So I need a way for Script X to modify the value of `var` for each `TestHandler` instance

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to forward the messages received at `DataHandler` to `TestHandler` so that you can call the script X to calculate `var` and then send it out to the connected clients. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I'd do - I'd create a new method on `TestHandler` which will serve 
one single purpose - take a message and send it to all the connected clients.

Before going into the code, I'd like to point out that it seems (conventionally) better to keep `ws_clients` inside the class instead of a global object. And use a `set` instead of a `list`.

```
class TestHandler(...):
    ws_clients = set() # use set instead of list to avoid duplicate connections

    def open(self):
        self.ws_clients.add(self)

    @classmethod
    def broadcast(cls, message):
        """Takes a message and sends to all connected clients"""
        for client in cls.ws_clients:
            # here you can calculate `var` depending on each client
            client.write_message(message)

    def on_close(self):
        # remove the client from `ws_clients`
        self.ws_client.remove(self)


# then you can call TestHandler.broadcast
# from anywhere in your code
# example:

class DataHandler(...):
    ...

    def on_message(self, message):
        # pass the message to TestHandler
        # to send out to connected clients
        TestHandler.broadcast(message)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you're a genius

Comment: @xyres I'm sorry, I know this is an old answer but could you please elaborate why `ws_clients` should not be a list? I know that set elements are guaranteed to be unique, but if I use a list and only call `ws_clients.append(self)` in the `open()` method, how can I end up with duplicates? Can `open()` be called multiple times?

Comment: @SimonKagwi You're right, `open` is called just once. I can't quite remember what my reasoning might have been while writing this answer, but now it seems redundant.

Comment: @xyres Thanks for your reply. I've been using a list for this on one of my projects and was wondering if I'd need to change it